# scatterplot3d: regression plane with residuals

Tags: r, scatter-plot, scatter3d

Using `scatterplot3d` in R, I'm trying to draw red lines from the observations to the regression plane:

```
wh <- iris$Species != "setosa"
x  <- iris$Sepal.Width[wh]
y  <- iris$Sepal.Length[wh]
z  <- iris$Petal.Width[wh]
df <- data.frame(x, y, z)

LM <- lm(y ~ x + z, df)
library(scatterplot3d)
G  <- scatterplot3d(x, z, y, highlight.3d = FALSE, type = "p")
G$plane3d(LM, draw_polygon = TRUE, draw_lines = FALSE)
```

[image: Regression Plane]

To obtain the 3D equivalent of the following picture:

[image]

In 2D, I could just use `segments`:

```
pred  <- predict(model) 
segments(x, y, x, pred, col = 2)
```

But in 3D I got confused with the coordinates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the advertising dataset from [An Introduction to Statistical Learning](http://faculty.marshall.usc.edu/gareth-james/ISL/data.html), you can do

```
advertising_fit1 <- lm(sales~TV+radio, data = advertising)
sp <- scatterplot3d::scatterplot3d(advertising$TV, 
                                   advertising$radio, 
                                   advertising$sales, 
                                   angle = 45)
sp$plane3d(advertising_fit1, lty.box = "solid")#,
           # polygon_args = list(col = rgb(.1, .2, .7, .5)) # Fill color
orig <- sp$xyz.convert(advertising$TV, 
                       advertising$radio, 
                       advertising$sales)
plane <- sp$xyz.convert(advertising$TV, 
                        advertising$radio,  fitted(advertising_fit1))
i.negpos <- 1 + (resid(advertising_fit1) > 0)
segments(orig$x, orig$y, plane$x, plane$y,
         col = c("blue", "red")[i.negpos], 
         lty = 1) # (2:1)[i.negpos]
sp <- FactoClass::addgrids3d(advertising$TV, 
                             advertising$radio, 
                             advertising$sales,
                             angle = 45,
                             grid = c("xy", "xz", "yz"))
```

[image]

And another **interactive** version using `rgl` package

```
rgl::plot3d(advertising$TV, 
             advertising$radio, 
             advertising$sales, type = "p", 
             xlab = "TV", 
             ylab = "radio", 
             zlab = "Sales", site = 5, lwd = 15)
rgl::planes3d(advertising_fit1$coefficients["TV"], 
              advertising_fit1$coefficients["radio"], -1, 
              advertising_fit1$coefficients["(Intercept)"], alpha = 0.3, front = "line")
rgl::segments3d(rep(advertising$TV, each = 2), 
                rep(advertising$radio, each = 2),
                matrix(t(cbind(advertising$sales, predict(advertising_fit1))), nc = 1),
                col = c("blue", "red")[i.negpos], 
                lty = 1) # (2:1)[i.negpos]
rgl::rgl.postscript("./pics/plot-advertising-rgl.pdf","pdf") # does not really work...
```

[image]

Comment: This is great! I fixed this eventually with some very ugly code. Thank you for this simpler solution, it will make it a lot easier to make an example for students.

Comment: @FransRodenburg See my edit! I could get the plane filled in the first version. If you find a way, please let me know!

Comment: Sure, I will write my own adaptation as an answer. Unfortunately `scatterplot3d` forces several arguments such as `cex`, `cex.main`, `cex.lab`, cex.axis`, so in the actual document I ended up just copying the entire function from github and adjusting it from there.

Answer (score 12):

I decided to include my own implementation as well, in case anyone else wants to use it.

### The Regression Plane

```
require("scatterplot3d")

# Data, linear regression with two explanatory variables
wh <- iris$Species != "setosa"
x  <- iris$Sepal.Width[wh]
y  <- iris$Sepal.Length[wh]
z  <- iris$Petal.Width[wh]
df <- data.frame(x, y, z)
LM <- lm(y ~ x + z, df)

# scatterplot
s3d <- scatterplot3d(x, z, y, pch = 19, type = "p", color = "darkgrey",
                     main = "Regression Plane", grid = TRUE, box = FALSE,  
                     mar = c(2.5, 2.5, 2, 1.5), angle = 55)

# regression plane
s3d$plane3d(LM, draw_polygon = TRUE, draw_lines = TRUE, 
            polygon_args = list(col = rgb(.1, .2, .7, .5)))

# overlay positive residuals
wh <- resid(LM) > 0
s3d$points3d(x[wh], z[wh], y[wh], pch = 19)
```

[image: regression plane]

### The Residuals

```
# scatterplot
s3d <- scatterplot3d(x, z, y, pch = 19, type = "p", color = "darkgrey",
                     main = "Regression Plane", grid = TRUE, box = FALSE,  
                     mar = c(2.5, 2.5, 2, 1.5), angle = 55)

# compute locations of segments
orig     <- s3d$xyz.convert(x, z, y)
plane    <- s3d$xyz.convert(x, z, fitted(LM))
i.negpos <- 1 + (resid(LM) > 0) # which residuals are above the plane?

# draw residual distances to regression plane
segments(orig$x, orig$y, plane$x, plane$y, col = "red", lty = c(2, 1)[i.negpos], 
         lwd = 1.5)

# draw the regression plane
s3d$plane3d(LM, draw_polygon = TRUE, draw_lines = TRUE, 
            polygon_args = list(col = rgb(0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8)))

# redraw positive residuals and segments above the plane
wh <- resid(LM) > 0
segments(orig$x[wh], orig$y[wh], plane$x[wh], plane$y[wh], col = "red", lty = 1, lwd = 1.5)
s3d$points3d(x[wh], z[wh], y[wh], pch = 19)
```

[image: residuals]

---

### The End Result:

While I really appreciate the convenience of the `scatterplot3d` function, in the end I ended up [copying the entire function from github](https://github.com/cran/scatterplot3d/blob/master/R/scatterplot3d.R), since several arguments that are in base `plot` are either forced by or not properly passed to `scatterplot3d` (e.g. axis rotation with `las`, character expansion with `cex`, `cex.main`, etc.). I am not sure whether such a long and messy chunk of code would be appropriate here, so I included the MWE above.

Anyway, this is what I ended up including in my book:

[image: end result]

*(Yes, that is actually just the iris data set, don't tell anyone.)*