# R: Customizing Scatterplots

Tags: r, plot, graph, regression, data-visualization

I am using the R programming language. I am trying to follow the answer posted in this previous stackoverflow post ([scatterplot3d: regression plane with residuals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47344850/scatterplot3d-regression-plane-with-residuals)) and add a "plane" to a scatterplot.

Suppose I have the following data:

```
my_data <- data.frame(read.table(header=TRUE,
row.names = 1,
text="
                         weight   height age
                      1  2998.958 15.26611  53
                      2  3002.208 18.08711  52
                      3  3008.171 16.70896  49
                      4  3002.374 17.37032  55
                      5  3000.658 18.04860  50
                      6  3002.688 17.24797  45
                      7  3004.923 16.45360  47
                      8  2987.264 16.71712  47
                      9  3011.332 17.76626  50
                      10 2983.783 18.10337  42
                      11 3007.167 18.18355  50
                      12 3007.049 18.11375  53
                      13 3002.656 15.49990  42
                      14 2986.710 16.73089  47
                      15 2998.286 17.12075  52
"))
```

I adapted the code to fit my example:

```
library(scatterplot3d)

model_1 <- lm(age ~ weight + height, data = my_data)

# scatterplot
s3d <- scatterplot3d(my_data$height, my_data$weight, my_data$age, pch = 19, type = "p", color = "darkgrey",
                     main = "Regression Plane", grid = TRUE, box = FALSE,  
                     mar = c(2.5, 2.5, 2, 1.5), angle = 55)

# regression plane
s3d$plane3d(model_1, draw_polygon = TRUE, draw_lines = TRUE, 
            polygon_args = list(col = rgb(.1, .2, .7, .5)))

# overlay positive residuals
wh <- resid(model_1) > 0
s3d$points3d(my_data$height, my_data$weight, my_data$age, pch = 19)
```

**Problem**: However, the "plane" appears to be absent :

[image]

Desired Result:

[image]

Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of `height` and `weight` caused the problem.

```
s3d <- scatterplot3d(my_data$weight, my_data$height,my_data$age, pch = 19, type = c("p"), color = "darkgrey",
                     main = "Regression Plane", grid = TRUE, box = FALSE,  
                     mar = c(2.5, 2.5, 2, 1.5), angle = 55)



# regression plane
s3d$plane3d(model_1, draw_polygon = TRUE, draw_lines = TRUE, 
            polygon_args = list(col = rgb(.1, .2, .7, .5)))

# overlay positive residuals
wh <- resid(model_1) > 0
s3d$points3d(my_data$height, my_data$weight, my_data$age, pch = 19)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!